Monospaced font is cut off at the top; Letters regular/bold have differernt width after fixing
My question is basically the same as this one:
Fixing font - some capital letters (e.g. 'Å', 'Ä', 'Ö') cut off from the top
But in my case it has nothing to do with an iOS App or Apple software. I am using the font 'Monoid' (https://larsenwork.com/monoid/) in Microsoft Visual Studio for software development, because this font has clearly distinguishable characters. In many fonts, also monospaced ones, the letters 1 (one), I (large i), l (lower L), and 0 (zero), O (large o) look very similar. Not so in Monoid, why I really like it:

Recently I found that some tall letters (e.g. Ä Ö Ü, which you rarely need when coding in English) are cut off at the top. The dots are hardly visible or not visible at all. Other software like MS Word and Notepad++ show the same problems. Thus I am pretty sure that it's a problem of the font.
A test in MS Word shows me that the letters of Monoid are too tall: The "normal" uppercase letters (A, B, etc.) already reach the upper selection border, so there is simply no place for the dots of Ä,Ö,Ü:

I don't know much about fonts, so I first contacted the author of the font, but unfortunately without response so far.
Then I tried to fix the problem myself and read explanations about how fonts are designed, like
https://fontbundles.net/blog/ask-a-font-creator-lets-talk-about-cut-off-text-in-microsoft-products
https://community.fontself.com/t/how-to-fix-letters-that-are-cut-off-at-the-top/230/8
Then I downloaded FontForge and after quite some trial and error I scaled all characters to 82%. Now they look fine in MS Word, Notepad++ and Visual Studio:

But now I got another problem: The font is not monospaced anymore when regular and bold characters are mixed. This only slightly visible in MS Word, but even more so in Visual Studio and Notepad++:


Other fonts in Visual Studio don't show this behaviour, so I think it's related to the font again.
Can anyone please help me to fix it?
Either by scaling down correctly or by fixing the regular/bold monospace problem?

Hi. Welcome to GDSE.  Sorry, but it is a software issue.  I tried using the font in some graphic design software: Adobe Illustrator, Inkscape, Photoshop and GIMP, and it works absolutely fine.  You shouldn't have to modify a font to use it in specific software.  The software you are using was likely never designed to use these letters in that particular font.

@BillyKerr Thanks for your reply! You are right. But the software I use is widely used among software developers and it works very well with many other monospaced fonts. But not with Monoid, so I strongly assume that this font has some parameters that don't play well with coding software. I like to find out these parameters and adapt them. Monoid is said to be a coding font, and not primarily meant for graphics design software, which likely handles fonts better in general. Maybe it has some parameters that primitive coding software does not understand. IMHO, still the font must be changed.

I'm not an expert with FontForge at all, and only have limited experience with it. However, it will probably have something to do with the width of the glyphs. In monospace fonts, all glyphs must be the exact same width. If you are rescaling or messing with the glyphs, that could be the source of the problem. See the FontForge FAQ

@BillyKerr I may use other (free) software as well, I'm not tied to FontForge. The resizing itself seemed to work. But bold characters have a different width, which is untypical for monospaced fonts. I don't know whether this is comes from resizing of from something else. However, thanks for your help and suggestions!
